# React: Calling two event handlers onClick and changing style of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a parent class-based component `A` and a child functional component `B`. Inside `B` I map over a list of names and render them as `li` elements, which `onClick` call the `onLanguageUpdate` handler declared in the parent component, and what this handler does is update the state to reflect the selected name.

**Question then**:

I need to call a second event handler in the same `onClick`, this time to change the color of the name the user has clicked on. I added a new property to the state, `color`, to represent a `className` that I can then toggle with the `handleStyleColorChange` handler. But how do I get the `li` elements in the child component to update their className (or style) based on the result of this handler? If I was doing all of this inside component A's `render` method, I could do `style={language === this.state.selectedLanguage ? {color: 'red'} : null}` on the `li` and call it a day.

```
// Component A
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import B from './B';

class A extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedLanguage: 'All',
      color: 'lang-black-text'
    };
  }

  handleUpdateLanguage = (language) => {
    return this.setState({ selectedLanguage: language });
  }

  handleStyleColorChange = (language) => {
    if (language === this.state.selectedLanguage) {
      return this.setState({ color: 'lang-red-text' });
    } else {
      return this.setState({ color: 'lang-black-text' });
    }
  }

  handleClick = (language) => {
    this.handleUpdateLanguage(language);
    this.handleStyleColorChange(language);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <LanguageList onLanguageUpdate={this.handleClick} />
    );
  }
}

export default A;
```

---

```
// Component B
import React from 'react';

const B = (props) => {
  const languages = ['English', 'Spanish', 'Japanese', 'Italian'];

  const languageListFormatted = languages.map(language => {
    return (
      <li
        key={language}
        onClick={() => props.onLanguageUpdate(language)}>{language}
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <ul className="languages">{languageListFormatted}</ul>
  );
}

export default B;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't manage the color from the parent comp, it needs to be done from the child comp. Then, send the `selectedLanguage` to the child and you are good.

```js
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

   this.state = {
      selectedLanguage: 'All',
      color: 'lang-black-text'
    };
  }

  handleUpdateLanguage = (language) => {
    return this.setState({ selectedLanguage: language });
  }

  handleStyleColorChange = (language) => {
    if (language === this.state.selectedLanguage) {
      return this.setState({ color: 'lang-red-text' });
    } else {
      return this.setState({ color: 'lang-black-text' });
    }
  }

  handleClick = (language) => {
    this.handleUpdateLanguage(language);
    this.handleStyleColorChange(language);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <B
        onLanguageUpdate={this.handleClick}
        selectedLanguage={this.state.selectedLanguage}
      />
    );
  }
}

const B = (props) => {
  const languages = ['English', 'Spanish', 'Japanese', 'Italian'];

  const languageListFormatted = languages.map(language => {
    return (
      <li
        key={language}
        style={props.selectedLanguage === language ? {background: 'yellow'} : {}}
        onClick={() => props.onLanguageUpdate(language)}>{language}
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <ul className="languages">{languageListFormatted}</ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <A />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something really simple. Thank you!